# Separating class definition and implementation in metatrader 4

Tags: metatrader4, metatrader5

Is it possible to separate class definition and implementation in MetaTrader 4, as in `C++` `.h` and `.cpp` files?
All MetaTrader examples have a class definition and implementation in the same file.
I would like to give header and `*.ex4` compiled files, as in C++ I would give header and `lib/dll` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this post](https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/362) that explains how to do.